# How to create a regex that matches two or more specific whole words?

Tags: regex, search, sublimetext3

### Purpose

The purpose of that RegEx is to use it on Sublime Text 3's "Search in Files" function that have support to Regular Expressions.

### Goal

My goal is to achieve a search that find specific whole words on specific file names, a plus is that the filename is defined as a string inside the file itself, so it maybe will make the things more easy.

## My deductions

I was thinking about how to perform it, and i realize that if i can create a regex that search two whole words on same file, it solves my problem, because the filename is inside the file too.

#### Example:

> I have many of files that are named `ListaController`, and i want to find only the ones that have `requires:` inside of it.
>
> `ListaController` is the name of the files that i want to search.
>
> `requires:` is the word i want to find insile files that are `ListaController`'s

So i need a RegEx that can match (`ListaController` and `requires:`) on the same file, to show only files that have the two words matched.

## What i've tried

The most close i did reach is that RegEx:

```
\bListaController\b|\brequires:\b
```

that resulted me only `ListaController` whole word results and none of `requires:` results.

So i need some help to create a RegEx that suits.

*Obs: if there is a easier/better solution to perform what i want on sublime without the use of regex, i will be grateful to see it and maybe it will be my final solution.*

Comment: `Searching 9563 files for "\bListaController\b|\brequires:" (regex)` ... and the result is files that have `requires:` that are not `ListaController`s

Comment: So do you actually want to find files that have both `ListaController` and `requires:` inside, or do you want to find files that are named `ListaController` and have `requires:` inside it? It's a bit confusing where you've said *"I have many of files that are named ListaController, and i want to find only the ones that have requires: inside of it."* and *"So i need a RegEx that can match (ListaController and requires:) on the same file"*

Comment: You cannot use a regex in the *where* field because it only accepts glob patterns that do not support word boundaries. So, you need to use the `\brequires:` regex in the regex field, and in *where* field, you may use something like `* ListaController *` to check the files that have the word inside spaces, then any other possible special char combinations round the search word.

Comment: @David sorry for the confusing sentence, but see, both of them solve my problem, "both `ListaController` and `requires:` inside;" and "files named `ListaController` that haves `includes:` inside it." the reason for both solving my problem is the fact that my files named `ListaController` have the name defined on them as a string on the first line of them. See why the two ways can solve my problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i have a option called `regex` to enable or not on the sublime find feature, thats why when i enable it i am capable of using regex on the search field. btw, i see difficulties when i try to use word boundary to more than 1 word.

Comment: You can only search for strings inside the file contents using regex, but not inside file names.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but in this case, the filenames are inside their files, its a default behaviour of my files to have names defined on the first line. So it gonna work in that specific case

Comment: Ok, then you may still use `(?s)^(?=.*?\bListaController\b)(?=.*?\brequires:)` - it will find a match in any file that contains both whole words `ListaController` and `requires:`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works, may you create a answer pointing out why mine regex didnt work and why yours works, answering directly to the question title, by the way, i got a answer below that solved my problem without the need of regex, but that solution is not answering the question title, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\bListaController\b|\brequires:\b` pattern is incorrect for the current task, because it searches for a whole word `ListController` **or** (the `|` is an [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)) `requires:` that is enclosed with word chars (digits, letters or `_`).

You want to match a file that contains both `ListController` and `requires:` as whole words, and that is possible with either alternation with `.*` in between the two patterns, or just using a [**lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regex. The latter type is actually preferred since it is less cumbersome, and only requires to use a subpattern only once.

You may use

```
(?s)\A(?=.*?\bListaController\b)(?=.*?\brequires:)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQudaL/1).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL mode enabling `.` to match line break chars that it does not match by default
- `\A` - start of the file
- `(?=.*?\bListaController\b)` - a positive lookahead that requires any 0+ chars, as few as possible (`*?` is a lazy quantifier), up to a whole word `ListaController` including it immediately to the right of the current position inside the string (that is, from the start of the file)
- `(?=.*?\brequires:)` - a positive lookahead that requires any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to a whole word `requires:` including it immediately to the right of the current position inside the string (that is, again, from the start of the file since lookaheads are zero-width assertions that do not move the regex index when their patterns are matched.)

Comment: that is very well detailed and explained, answering exactly what i've asked, obviously the correct answer, so i marked it. that was done for future reference, answering directly the title of question. *even if the easier solution to solve is problem is a more simple thing that does not envolve regex.* (does not matter, that is a plus.)

Answer (score 1):

If you will search a string in file, you can use a filename filter, using the "Where" feature. Place `requires:` in find box and `*ListaController*` in where box

Comment: See, i tried to put `*ListaController*` in where box and `requires:` on find box. It works, but, it searchs on the whole context, inside all of the projects that i have, instead of searching only on the folder that i specified.

Comment: In where box, you can put more than one filter, click on the button on the right of where box, then click on `add folder`

Comment: Now, it solved my problem totally, but the question is "How to create a regex that matches two or more specific whole words" so i wonder what i do to this answer/question.

Comment: Does not matter, we did what Perl says since 1987: "There's more than one way to do it"